# How do I make CSS sharp "V" like horizontal corners for `<legend>` and `<fieldset>`?

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

How do I make in CSS sharp "V" like horizontal corners?
Corners that look like this <   > as if the corners were arose to left and right in both the `<legend>` and then in the `<fieldset>` as well.

```css
#FieldsetSeekBox {
  padding: 8px 1px;
  border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

#LegendStyle {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  font: bold 13px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="FieldsetSeekBox">
  <legend id="LegendStyle">&nbsp; Web Search &nbsp;</legend>
  <input type="text" name="u" size="70" value="" placeholder="Type your Search here and click Search..." id="SeekBox">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, so a picture would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to set some content with the css pseudo elements `:before` or `:after`. Then by setting the border widths for top/bottom you can create a triangle shape.

See [css-triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/#article-header-id-2) demo, or below example.

```css
#FieldsetSeekBox {
  padding: 8px 1px;
  border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

#LegendStyle {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  font: bold 13px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#LegendStyle:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #a1a1a1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="FieldsetSeekBox">
  <legend id="LegendStyle">&nbsp; Web Search &nbsp;</legend>
  <input type="text" name="u" size="70" value="" placeholder="Type your Search here and click Search..." id="SeekBox">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you it is perfect. I also switched these two for the `:before` code `left: -10px; border-right: 10px solid #a1a1a1;`. It works perfectly.